# Replacing QPen's - How Do I Delete

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a GUI which will allow the user to modify ellipses using mouse/QSpinBox events on top of a background picture.

I want to set it up so that when a user clicks on an ellipse, the ellipse changes color and has been "selected."

I am using QGraphicsView/Scene with QGraphicsEllipseItem.  Here in lies my problem, the `setPen(QPen & const)` call is a reference thus:

- If I allocate a pen on the stack and pass it in, I get a segfault.
- If I allocate a pen on the heap, it doesn't get deleted when I set a new pen
- The accessor method returns a copy of the pen

Anyways, I must be approaching this wrong, could any offer any suggestions?

P.S. - I would like to avoid making yet ANOTHER member variable.  I am going to have many ellipses, each one should not have its own pen variable!

---

This code will cause a segfault:

```
void MyClass::SetupEllipses()
{
    QPen pen();
    pen.setColor(QColor(255,0,0));
    pen.setWidth(2);

    m_ellipse = new QGraphicsItemEllipse(); //This is a member variable of MyClass
    m_ellipse->setRect(some ssize here);
    m_ellipse->setPen(pen);

    m_graphicsview->scene()->addItem(m_ellipse); //m_graphicsview is also a member variable of MyClass and has had a scene added to it.
}
```

Comment: The `QPen` is copied into `QPainter` when set, that's why the 'normal' procedure is just to create it on the stack inside the painting method.  Where exactly are you getting the segfault?

Comment: Well this isn't being called in a `paint()` event.  I'm instantiating a `QGraphicsEllipseItem` for my class and setting its pen.  So the segfault would occur when I leave my `SetupStuff()` method.

Comment: `QPen` is not designed to be created on the heap, nor does `QGraphicsItem` store a reference to it - so post a stack trace from your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I allocate a pen on the stack and pass it in, I get a segfault.

That's the right way - if you get a segfault, that's certainly not due to the QPen.
Post your code and debugger stack trace.

Each QGraphicsEllipseItem will store a (light-weight) copy of the QPen anyway, so creating QPen instances on the heap is nonsensical and error-prone.
Do not worry about too many QPen instances. QPen uses [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html), i.e. if you share the same unmodified pen, the copies are cheap.

Comment: `QGraphicsEllipseItem` will store a reference to the QPen it seems, so when you allocate a QPen in the stack of a `Setup()` type function, when the function leaves and the ellipse is drawn later, that `QPen` has been deallocated.